# Neo4j java unmanaged server extension not running

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to run the neo4j java unmanaged server extension example given below
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/developer-resources/tree/gh-pages/language-guides/java/server-extension

i followed the readme and executed "mvn compile exec:java".. 
but it looks like it is for JDBC driver.

my question is: How do i run the example server extension...?

./Zahoor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the jar file using `mvn package` and drop the jar into your server's `plugins` folder. In `conf/neo4j-server.conf` set the following option:

```
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=example.extension.movies=/<mybaseurlpath>
```